# ¿Cómo hacer que se cierre un JFrame y se abra otro a la vez después de determinado tiempo?

Tags: java

Esto es lo que intente poner pero no me funciona:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


 public void Esperar(){


         try {
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         dispose();
         Menu m = new Menu();
         m.setVisible(true);           
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir que no funciona, que es lo que pasa?

Answer (score 0):

seguramente te darán alguna respuesta mucho más sencilla, pero te comparto mi experiencia.

Trabajar con una aplicación de escritorio en spring me hizo darme cuenta que normalmente mantenemos las referencias a otros frames dentro del frame haciendo que el orden de creación importe mucho y se vuelva súper complejo, al igual que el manejo de la navegación, es por este motivo que yo elegí para evitar el problema de dependencias cíclicas usar el patrón visitador que forma arte de los así denominados [patrones-de-diseño](/questions/tagged/patrones-de-dise%c3%b1o).

Un visitador es una clase que te indica como hacer una transición de un objeto a otro, si lo piensas como un problema más abstracto se trata de un grafo dirigido y las opciones comunes consisten en una matriz de adyacencia o un ADT (tipo de dato abstracto) para simular un árbol, y en esencia el visitador es el ADT para el arista.

La forma más simple es poner un método para transicionar a cada frame posible de tu aplicación y en aquellos en que no quieras que pase nada mandar un error en tiempo de ejecución para indicar una transición inválida.

Esto lo puedes lograr con poco código poniendo métodos por defecto en una interfaz, pero en lo personal prefiero hacerlo en una clase abstracta para asegurarme de no olvidar ninguno o que si algún desarrollador novato llegue a meterle mano no pueda cometer errores.

```
public class MenuVisitor extends NavigationHandler {
    
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void goToInventoryManagement(JFrame origin) {
        InventoryManagement inventoryManagement = context.getBean(InventoryManagement.class);
        inventoryManagement.setVisible(true);
        origin.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void goToShopping(JFrame origin) {
        ShoppingWindow shoppingWindow = context.getBean(ShoppingWindow.class);
        shoppingWindow.setVisible(true);
        origin.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void goToOrderManagement(JFrame origin) {
        OrderManagement orderManagement = context.getBean(OrderManagement.class);
        orderManagement.setVisible(true);
        origin.dispose();
    }

.
.
.

}
```

Eso del context es de un framework llamado [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), pero esencialmente vas a una clase que tiene las referencias a las instancias de tus frames.

Tus llamadas las haces así:

```
navigationHandler.goToMenu(this);
```

y en tu `navigationHandler` la implementación es solo la firma del método

```
public abstract void goToMenu(JFrame origin);
```

Ahora una observación un poco morbosa acerca de las esperas es que realmente no creo que quieras esperar milisegundos, sino a algún evento, y para el caso del método que usas `Thread.sleep` no te puedo garantizar que el tiempo sea el mismo en distintos equipos debido a la variación de los relojes y demás detalles, por lo que te recomiendo usar una librería muy mona para Java 8 llamada [awaitility](/questions/tagged/awaitility), que te permite esperar n cantidad de segundos máximo hasta que ocurra el evento que deseas como por ejemplo que tu frame sea visible o que la carga de datos desde un web service se complete.